# Permission denied in home dir after running sudo gcloud... (macOS Catalina)

Tags: macos, unix, gcloud

Friends, I did a mistake here and kind of screw up with my system. I needed to connect to my cluster and ran:

`sudo gcloud container clusters get-credentials quotes-cluster-testing`.

After doing this, I started having a lot of permission problems. I can't, for instance, cd into my home directory. I run `ls -l` and the permissions of my directory looked like this:

```
drwx------ 72 marcelo  staff  2304 Jan 10 18:14 marcelo
```

After running `chmod 755 marcelo`, I had `drwxr-xr-x+ 72 marcelo  staff  2304 Jan 10 18:14 marcelo` but after sometime the permissions change back to  `drwx------` and I start having permission problems again.

Any idea how can I start trying to fix this? I didn't want to reinstall the whole system if there was another way to fix the problem.

I am using macOS Catalina version 10.15.7.

Comment: I can't emagine how [this command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials) could have messed it up. This has to be some macOS issue, maybe try to search at their forums.

Comment: Yeap, but the problem is that I ran it with sudo and shouldn't have, so who knows. I started having this problem immediately after running the command.